# Azure adal broker authentication prompts account select everytime app opens up azure-activedirectory-library-for-react-native

Tags: azure, react-native, adal

I'm using Durgaprasad-Budhwani - azure-activedirectory-library-for-react-native plugin, and I've configured it to use the broker authentication using Microsoft Authenticator.

The main issue we have is that it prompts to select the account every time the app is loaded. So instead of returning the token it retrieved the first time, it asks the user to select the account in every instance.

Plugin github - https://github.com/Durgaprasad-Budhwani/azure-activedirectory-library-for-react-native

**React native version - 0.59.1
react-native-azure-adal - 1.0.9**

We've tried this using the guide provided by the plugin example project here -

https://github.com/Durgaprasad-Budhwani/azure-activedirectory-library-for-react-native/blob/master/example/index.android.js

**Expected result**
Plugin is supposed return the authDetails object after the first login, without prompting Microsoft Authenticator.

**Current Result**
But the in this scenario it prompts the user to select the account from Microsoft Authenticator.